# List key value with unique key as an object or enum

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

**Question**

- I would like a list of key value pair such as a HashMap for instance or other if recommended.
- This list should contains unique keys objects used to retrieve the values.
- Keys should NOT be a STRING, since string is not unique and any value can be passed.
- Also constants are limited and are using the concepts of strings as well and should not be considered.

**Example**

- What is wanted is for instance list[Color.Red] = "Red".
- At this stage, i have created an enum containing all the keys.
  For instance enum Color{RED,BLUE} then add it to a new HashMap.
- So the only way to retrieve a color, is to use the enum as a key list[Color.RED].

**Implementation**

```
public final static Map<Color, String> colors = new HashMap<>();
public final static enum Color{RED, BLUE;}
static
{
   colors.put(RED, "red");
   colors.put(BLUE, "blue");
}
public static string getColor(Color color)
{
   return colors.get(color);
}
```

**Need Help**

Is there a type of Collection in Java that could do the job ?
If not then what might be the best practice to do so ?

Comment: Is your example real in that you want `Color.RED` to return the value of "Red"? Because you can override the `.toString()` or add a method to the `enum` to return a particular value, and enums are an array, and unique. But using an enum as a key is a perfectly legitimate way to constrain the input.

Comment: You can use constructor of enum to add a value, so mapping is essential.

Comment: yes you are right that was the way to do it, i have added a potential solution at the end of this thread. cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Potential Solution**

After checking around enum and its possibilities, there is a way to assign values to a Key in an enum, like follow.

- Create a new enum and assign Key such as public enum Color{RED;}.
- Add a constructor parameter to it such as public enum Color{RED("red");}
- Add a constructor to the enum such as public enum Color{RED("red"); Color(){}}
- Add a new field inside enum called value such as private String value; public String getValue() {return value;}
- Set field value in constructor of enum such as Color(String value) {this.value = value;}
- Enum work in that way, for each Key you add it creates a new instance field String value linked to the Key, then it will use the constructor you have declared to save the value.

**Full Implementation**

```
public enum Color
{
   //[PROP]
   RED("red"),
   GREEN("green"),
   BLUE("blue");

   private String value;
   public String getValue {return value;}

   //[BUILD]
   Color(String value) {this.value = value;}

   //[UTIL]
   Color[] getKeys() {return this.values;} //values method is already a method existing in enum class, we are just proposing another method name here as a facade for simplicity.
}
```

- If we want to retrieve an item we just simply do Color.RED.value, in this way only existing keys returned wanted value.
- Note that value doesn't needs to be the name of the key but could be a totally different value.

Please comment if you have any simpler solution without putting more complexity to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**The keys are unique in all maps**. Add duplicate key, then it will be overwritten.. The difference between the various maps implementations concern the possibility of null keys, the order of iteration and concurrency issues.

exemple:

```
Map hm = new HashMap();
hm.put("1", new Integer(1));
hm.put("2", new Integer(2));
hm.put("3", new Integer(3));
hm.put("4", new Integer(4));
hm.put("1", new Integer(5));// value integer 1 is overwritten by 5
```

In addition, **Map key are generic**, you can put what you want, not only String, exemple:

```
Map<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put(10, "1");
```

Comment: Thank you @davidr, in your example you can basically try to retrieve values that does not exists in your List. This is the problem we try to solve. For instance hm.get(12); won't return any value. We are trying to force the developer to enter only values that exist by using an enum as a key value pair. Your answer does not answer the question.